# Adding images to Assets.xcassets, won't display on LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, launch-screen

I am recently having problems displaying images in my LaunchScreen.storyboard. I don't know if this is related or not, but I upgraded to Xcode 9 right before trying to add an Image View. Here are the scenarios that I am trying.

Working:

- I can display images that I had in my Assets folder prior to upgrading. This works in both Main.storyboard and LaunchScreen.storyboard.
- I can display new images on my View Controllers that are in my Main.storyboard

Not Working:

- I cannot display new images in my LaunchScreen.storyboard.

I am wondering if I may have unintentionally changed a setting for my Launchscreen.storyboard as the problem does not exist in my Main.storyboard, but I don't know what setting this would be. But if this is the case, I don't know why it would display old images, but not new ones.

I don't believe that the images are the problem because I have duplicated the images in Finder, added the new image to my project, and I can still only get the original image to display (the duplicate won't). I have also tried images of several different sizes and types (.png and .jpg).

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you have to do 5 things to get it to work. 1 - Update the launch image. 2 - Clean Project, and deleted derived data. 3 - Restart Xcode. 4 - Delete app from phone, and restart it. 5 - rebuild and install the app

Comment: @AntonTheDev Could you clarify something for me? What do I need to do to delete the launch image?

Comment: @AntonTheDev This got it working, thanks!

Comment: I just posted a formal answer, hopefully it helps someone else out one day :)

Comment: @AntonTheDev The answer looks good. It does have "Restart Xcode" listed as steps 4 & 5.

Comment: Just updated it to reflect the correct steps :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the image is cached in iOS for quick launch, it does not get updated right away. These are the steps to follow if you want to see the new launch image appear.

The following steps should erase the cached image that was on the device prior, and display the new launch image accordingly upon rebuild in step 8.

**Step 1** : Update the image in the Assets.xcassets

**Step 2** : In Xcode, go to Project -> Clean

**Step 3** : In Xcode go to File -> Preferences. Navigate to the Locations Tab, and click the little arrow next to derived data

[image]

**Step 4** : Delete the DerivedData folder that opens up after clicking the arrow

**Step 5** : Restart Xcode

**Step 6** : Delete the app on the test device

**Step 7** : Restart the test device

**Step 8** : Build & Run the app on the test device